# requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a program to scrape new real estate listings data. The program works fine at first. It get the links to the different properties and then starts going through them. Unfortunately after going through a few of them this error comes up. I tried to creat an exception that captures the error (requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool) and restarts going through the properties where it let off but after going through a couple of more properties the error comes back and every time more offen until it just keeps trying to start again.

I've tried different solutions in similar threads but can´t make them work.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 157, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 61, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 300, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: : Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 436, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.infocasas.com.uyhttps', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //rck38r446m.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ProdStage (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Ejercicios\ScraperInfocasas1.0.py", line 170, in 
    r = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.xxxxx.com.uyhttps', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //rck38r446m.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ProdStage (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))